# Rails 4 override a model attribute with parent attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best way to achieve the following in Rails 4? Parent and child model have the same attribute. If child model hasn't set said attribute then it inherits from the parent, otherwise, it renders its own value.

I tried to create a method in the child method with the same name as the model attribute to do the logic, but that causes a stack level too deep error.

```
  def age_of_seniority
    age_of_seniority.present? ? age_of_seniority : borough.age_of_seniority
  end
```

## Update

I don't want to change the method name, I would like to be able to access it as a normal attribute

Comment: Try changing the method name

Comment: define it as `class_attribute :age_of_seniority`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `read_attribute`

```
def age_of_seniority
  read_attribute(:age_of_seniority) || borough.age_of_seniority
end
```

Comment: sorry, i should have said i want to be able to access it as a normal attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Call super:

```
def seniority_age
  super || borough.age_of_seniority
end
```

A simple example:

```
class Parent     

  attr_accessor :seniority_age     

end     

class Child < Parent     

  def seniority_age     
    super||'foo'     
  end     

end     

c = Child.new    
puts c.seniority_age    
c.seniority_age = "bar"     
puts c.seniority_age
```

returns:

foo

bar

Answer (score 0):

You are recursively calling the method from within the method, this of course will cause a stack overflow.

```
def age_of_seniority
    age_of_seniority.present? ? age_of_seniority : borough.age_of_seniority
end
```

If the age_of_seniority is stored in the instance variable, you access it with:

```
@age_of_seniority
```

So in your code:

```
def age_of_seniority
  @age_of_seniority.present? ? @age_of_seniority : borough.age_of_seniority
end
```

And to call the overrided method from parent, you can just use `super`.
not quite sure what's `borough.age_of_seniority` doing.